# Issue initialising a struct

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
typedef struct{
  char name[64];
} Cat;

Cat createCat(char name[64]) {
  Cat newCat;

  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 64; i += 1) {
    newCat.name[i] = name[i];
  }

  return newCat;
}

Cat exampleCat = createCat("Bob");
```

It compiles with the following error:

> initializer element is not constant

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Cat exampleCat = createCat("Bob");
```

You can't do a method call here. Initialize `exampleCat` somewhere else.

This is explained in the spec, section 6.7.8/4:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Comment: This is still only half an answer, together with Bo's it would make a perfect one :)

Comment: @JensGustedt: They don't have the same functionality, though.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to write a function to initialize a struct. You can just use an initializer where you give values to each member (only one here).

```
Cat exampleCat = {"Bob"};
```

Also note that if you instead had used C++, you would have the option of using a dynamic initializer, and the code would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
void createCat(Cat * kitty, char name[64]) {
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 64; i += 1) {
    kitty->name[i] = name[i];
  }
}

Cat exampleCat;
createCat(&exampleCat, "Bob");
```

Comment: The problem of attempting to invoke a function at a global scope still exists

Comment: You can't seperate code blocks by adding blank lines. so rather than adding meaningless filler, I'll just let the asker use his brain.